# PHP Iterate over array and get count for each item

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing dates, I want to iterate over the array to get a count for how many times a date appears. I want the data to be displayed in a chart so the result needs to be in the form

```
data:[
    [count, date],
    [count, date],
    [count, date]
]
```

so that the count for each date is in an array with it.

I was having some difficulty trying to find a good way to do this, or if there was a method that I may have overlooked

Comment: Where are you getting the array from? Also what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of [**array_column()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), and [**array_count_values()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

with `array_column` you will get second element of each sub array, and `array_count_values` will give you count.

```
array_count_values(array_column($array, 1));
```

> `array_column` — Return the values from a single column in the input
>   array (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)
>
> `array_count_values` — Counts all the
>   values of an array (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

Test Results, for array specified like below, as you requested

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php

    $array = [
        [1, '02-10-2017'],
        [2, '02-10-2017'],
        [3, '04-10-2017'],
        [4, '10-10-2017']
    ];

    print_r(array_count_values(array_column($array, 1)));
?>

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [02-10-2017] => 2
    [04-10-2017] => 1
    [10-10-2017] => 1
)
```

Comment: Please dont post code-only answers. Add a bit of explanaition why this works and how.

Comment: Thank you I didnt realise these were methods, I guess I wasnt looking properly at the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your array is like so :

```
<?php 
$dates = ['02-10-2017', '02-10-2017', '01-09-2017'];
?>
```

You can use `array_count_values` like this :

```
<?php
    print_r(array_count_values($dates));
?>
```

The output will be something like :

```
Array
(
    [02-10-2017] => 2
    [01-09-2017] => 1
)
```

If you want the keys to be the count, you can use the `array_flip` function.